# MainMenu with Images (WinForms, C#)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, menu, program-entry-point

I have a MainMenu in my app and I would like to have little icons relevant to the Item in each menu. But the MainMenu control does not support this.

I would use the MenuStrip control, though that is a pretty ugly option in my opinion.

Does anybody have any suggestions? Are there any free/open source alt's out there, or would it be easy/possible to implement that feature into the existing MainMenu control?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I very often come across problems like this, and its rare when I can find free code that I can use. What I do is I try to derive my own controls to make things happen, which is pain... but what you gonna do... Regarding your problem I just found [this post](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_graphics/customizinguserinterfaces/article.php/c6135/), and I think thats exactly what you need. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link m0s. After looking at that link (while it is exactly what I want), I figured that it may be a pain to create my own, but in the future, less work will be required. So, I'll just create my own